# Setting line height on UIFont

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that you can set line-height on UI labels and UItextview. However, my question is how can I set a line-height of a UIfont? is this possible?

Doing something like this doesn't work as line-height is a get only property and it doesn't seem to be a `minimum line Height` or `maximum line Height` properties for UIFont

```
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .bold)
    font.lineHeight = 12
```

Comment: You cannot change the "line height" of a font... but you *can* set the `minimumLineHeight` and `maximumLineHeight` of an attributed string/

Answer (score 0):

You can see the value of lineheight of your font via this extension :

```
CGFloat GetLineHeightForFont(CTFontRef iFont)
{
    CGFloat lineHeight = 0.0;
 
    check(iFont != NULL);
 
    // Get the ascent from the font, already scaled for the font's size
    lineHeight += CTFontGetAscent(iFont);
 
    // Get the descent from the font, already scaled for the font's size
    lineHeight += CTFontGetDescent(iFont);
 
    // Get the leading from the font, already scaled for the font's size
    lineHeight += CTFontGetLeading(iFont);
 
    return lineHeight;
}
```

Comment: This gets the lineheight value, however I am trying to set the line height not get it.

Comment: You right but I searched on the net it seems it is not possible and never need to set the lineheigt with your way